# My link to my podcasts doesn't open the Podcasts app anymore. Any ideas?

Tags: ios, swift, podcast

Here's the code that I've got:

```
@IBAction func podcastsButtonLinktoWebsite(sender: AnyObject) {

    let podcastsAddress = "pcast://clearview-church-shreveport/id404066921"

    let escapedPodcastsAddress = podcastsAddress.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())

    let url = NSURL(string: escapedPodcastsAddress!)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)

}
```

Before the latest update, it worked fine, but now if just closes my app when I click on that button.  Any ideas?

I've also tried:

```
    let podcastsAddress = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/clearview-church-shreveport/id404066921"
```

but that didn't work either.

I'm a newbie.  Grace and forgiveness please.  I so appreciate all of you! I'm learning so much!

Mali

Comment: If it closes your application do you get a crash log or any console output?

Comment: I don't get any console output and honestly don't think i have a crash log enabled(?)...

Comment: I did a little debugging and discovered that it's crashing at this line:    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)